# Waiting for element by.css() in protractor

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

I have some code in which `$scope.$broadcast` triggers an event which executes an `element.addClass()`

code in my controller

```
ctrlr.rollDice = function(){
 .... do some stuff 
 $scope.$broadcast('eventType', args);
}
```

code in my directive

```
scope.$on('eventType', function(){ element.addClass('class'); });
```

I am trying to **wait** until the event has fired and the `element.addClass` is executed in my protractor test using

```
browser.wait(element(by.css('.activate')).isPresent,15000).then(function(isPresent){
      expect(isPresent).toBe(true);
    });
```

However, I get the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWebElements' of undefined

How do I **wait** for the element with the class *.activate* to *show up* ??

Note that `element` can be any random visible element ...it is just to set the class. Also if I were to run the project in my actual web browser....everything runs successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser.wait(() => $('.activate')).isPresent() ,15000);
expect($('.activate').isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Or the ES5 version

```
browser.wait(function() {
  return $('.activate').isPresent();
}, 15000);
expect($('.activate').isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

**Note:** `element(by.css('.abc')) === $('.abc')`